# @media queries and image swapping

Tags: html, css, media-queries, imagesource

I want the image in my site to completely change when the browser is resized.

I've been using media-queries, but I can't seem to get it right.
Any thoughts/tips?

Comment: Welcome - if you're new, consider reading [ask] in order to get up to speed on how to formulate good questions here. For starters, showing the code you currently have will make it tremendously easier for us to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: This question [may be experiencing the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389760/was-my-edit-too-short).

Answer (score 72):

In the future please add code you've tried.

if it's an `image` tag you can use a class. Hide the second image on page load and show + hide image 1 at a certain screen size like so:

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="image1"/>
<img src="image.jpg" class="image2"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.image2{
   display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){ //some value
   .image1{
     display: none;
   }

   .image2{
     display: block;
   }
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1 - SHRINK BROWSER**](http://jsfiddle.net/vk02svc6/)

## **OR**

If it's a `background-image` you can simply swap the image:

**HTML**

```
<div class="example"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example{
   background-image: url("example.jpg");
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){ //some value

   .example{
      background-image: url("example2.jpg");
   }
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2 - SHRINK BROWSER**](http://jsfiddle.net/vk02svc6/1/)

Comment: @AaratiAkkapeddi you're welcome. If this is the answer you were looking for can you check this off as resolved?

Comment: Will the first solution result in the browser downloading the unneeded image?

Comment: @Ally browsers don't download images unless they need to show them

Comment: @vivoconunxino: Maybe every <img> is always loaded? https://litmus.com/community/discussions/7047-does-display-none-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Comment: In the first example you should have different src (as you source code reveils).

Answer (score 46):

This can be done using the HTML5 `picture` element which doesn't require CSS for changing `img` elements on specified media queries. If you're intrested in this approach, do be aware of its [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) which does **NOT** include IE, though there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) for older browsers.

```html
<h1>Resize Window</h1>
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1400" media="(min-width: 1400px)"/>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1200" media="(min-width: 1200px)"/>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/800" media="(min-width: 800px)"/>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/600" media="(min-width: 600px)"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="example"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: I usually use the CSS methods described below, but this method seems like an excellent method for feature photos when you know you want them to crop differently in different media.

Comment: The big issue with `@media` and using `display:none;` is that the image is still being loaded.  Even if you apply a mobile-first approach, you're still having larger displays load both images as opposed to 1. This method will actually only fetch the required image you need on load, and then load other size images in as the viewport changes.

Comment: Supporting @ekfuhrmann: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/7047-does-display-none-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Comment: Exactly @ekfuhrmann is correct. All the people saying to use display none are actually bad front end developers. Would not hire. Good answer ekfuhrmann!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `content` property to insert your image. However, images included like this could be difficult to style. (*Run code snippet in full screen before resizing browser*)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    div img {
        display:none;
    }
    div::before {
        content: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66");
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Resize this window to see image change</p>
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66" width="200px" />
</div>
```