# Replace image with media query not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working with an HTML template, and I'm trying to replace the site's logo based on browser size using media queries.

I am trying the technique I found here: [@media queries and image swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853884/media-queries-and-image-swapping)

My custom.css file has this code:

```
.test-mobile-logo{
   display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){           
    .test-main-logo{
     display: none;
   }

   .test-mobile-logo{
     display: block;
   }
}
```

My html file has this code for the logo:

```
<div class="logo"> 
                <a href="index.html" >
                    <img src="images/logo-dark.png" alt="" class="test-main-logo">
                    <img src="images/logo-main.png" alt="" class="test-mobile-logo">
                </a> 
            </div>
```

The page is showing both images at once though.  But when I remove my style.css file, the images finally show one at a time and replace properly.

The style.css file: http://demos.webicode.com/html/lucian/html/css/style.css

I'm not sure what the conflict is, I'm still new to CSS.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [-click- suggestion to test your website](http://troy.labs.daum.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this style in your css that overrides your display styles.

```
img {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Remove the `!important` to make your media-query work.

Comment: @OP the **!important** clause can cause all sorts of unintended side effects like this, and should be strictly avoided, unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning CSS so that helped a lot! Thank you too @Bosworth99 for the additional comment

Comment: Make sure removing it doesnt break something else on you site.
Good luck learning! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @HenrikhKantuni use a background image and change the background image in the css media query.

Otherwise users will always be downloading 2 images, that's one unnecessary http request and kilobytes the user will be requesting, especially over mobile networks you want to reduce this as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

as @VincentOrback mentioned just delete the `!important` from `img` selector

> **Better technique:** use background-image instead and just change the url, or **(even better)** use [CSS Sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)