# Auto adjust head height with an image

Tags: css, image, header, height

I have an image that is 1903 x 475 pixels and I have a set in my header.  I had to set the header height at 475px just the see the image.  Everything looks great until I test for smaller screens.  I add a background-size of 100% which is allowing the image to auto adjust but the header height stays at 475px.  I feel am over looking a simple technique but I need the header to match the height of the image as the screen size gets smaller.

**Here is what i have for the header and the image:**

```
*.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-static-top {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background: url(../images/flavor-westbg.jpg)top center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    min-height: 475px;
    width: auto;
}*
```

**Oh one last thing.  I can only tweak the CSS for this project.**

Comment: please share header html code to debug easily

Answer (score 0):

what about css media queries??

[Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

[@media queries and image swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853884/media-queries-and-image-swapping)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using bootstrap. One Thing you could try is "padding-top: px;" for the photo or  you are placing the folder under. I had to use padding to fix a similar problem with a jumbotron.