# JS breaking on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a website where I am using two different logos on scroll, but I use only one if the screen is less than 1024px.

Everything works as expected, except on screen resize that this breaks. It doesn't show any of the logos on the header, but if I refresh the page, it works...

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="container clearfix" >
      <h2 id="logo"><a rel="home" href="#">LOGO ONE</a></h2>
      <h2 id="logo2"><a rel="home" href="#"><span>LOGO</span> <br/>TWO</a></h2>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Main menu animation
    $(function () {
    if($(window).width() >= 1023){
        var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;
        var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $w.scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset ) {   
            $("#logo").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
            $("header").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
        } else {
            $("#logo2").fadeIn(2000)
            $("#logo").fadeOut('slow');
            $("header").css({"overflow": "visible"});
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: You might want to set a minimum width and height for your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS code you currently have, will only be triggered when the page is loaded, since you're using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Main menu animation
});
```

jQuery has the [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event handler, which will trigger when the browser window is resized, so I suggest using the following code, if you really want to stick with a JS solution. Although I find the usage of media queries in this specific situation a lot better/smoother:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   //Main menu animation
   $(function () {
    if($(window).width() >= 1023){
       var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;
       var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ( $w.scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset ) {   
         $("#logo").fadeIn(1000);
         $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
         $("header").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
       } else {
         $("#logo2").fadeIn(2000)
         $("#logo").fadeOut('slow');
         $("header").css({"overflow": "visible"});
       }
    });
   }
});
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: This breaks the website... any idea why?

Comment: I can't debug the code entirely, because the selector you use in your code `$("#section--4")` will not be found since it is not in your HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@media screen and (min-width: 1024) {
logo {
  display: none;
}}` to hide your logo. You don't need JS to handle visible depending on with. Also you can do this `object.addEventListener("resize", myScript);`

Comment: How do you want me to use object.addEventListener("resize", myScript); ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire the event on window resize and run your code, what you did is just run the code on page load

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  // call your function here
});
```

**See code snippet:**

```js
function myfunction() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 1023) {
    var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;
    var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($w.scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset) {
        $("#logo").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
        $("header").css({
          "overflow": "hidden"
        });
      } else {
        $("#logo2").fadeIn(2000)
        $("#logo").fadeOut('slow');
        $("header").css({
          "overflow": "visible"
        });
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  myfunction();
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  myfunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container clearfix">
  <h2 id="logo"><a rel="home" href="#">LOGO ONE</a></h2>
  <h2 id="logo2"><a rel="home" href="#"><span>LOGO</span> <br/>TWO</a></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I modified $(document).ready(function() with your code, but it breaks the website...

Comment: @patie i made a snippet see if its the same what you did

Answer (score 0):

This is because the code that deals with window width is called before scroll meaning that when the window resizes the logo will remain the same until the pages I refreshed in the browser and the code is reloaded. To fix this use jQuery's `$(element).resize()` handler to fix this. Another solution is to use ccs media queries with a max-width of 1024px

Documentation links

https://api.jquery.com/resize/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

I can't stress enough how much you should be doing this with media queries as Sergey suggests.

It can be done with JS and event handlers, but CSS `@media` queries will be your friend here.

Comment: I already tried with media queries and it didn't work, that's why I had to do it with jQuery...

Comment: If it isn't working with media queries then something's wrong.

`@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px)`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to listen to the [resize jQuery event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) if you want to respond to window resize.

That said, my suggestion is to manage it in css using media queries.
To do that, have a look at this answer: [@media queries and image swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853917/4149456)